# Schauder-type estimates for polyharmonic operators in a smooth domain of $R^N$

Tags: elliptic-pde

Let $L$ be an elliptic operator of the form
$$ 
Lu := (-1)^m \sum_{|\alpha|=2m} a_\alpha(x)  D^\alpha u + \sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2m-1} b_\alpha (x) D^\alpha u 
$$
with smooth coefficients and $u$ defined in a smooth bounded domain of $R^N$, $N \geq 2m$. Are there some kind of Schauder type estimates for solutions of the problem
$$
  L u = f(x),
$$
coupled with some boundary conditions (for example Dirichlet or Navier boundary conditions).

As far as I know such kind or results exist but for operator of the form
$$
  L u = (-\Delta)^m u + \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 2m - 1} c_\alpha(x) D^\alpha u.
$$

Comment: Estimates in Hölder-Zygmund spaces hold for any elliptic (pseudo-)differential boundary value problem. See e.g. [here](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/12593/10609).